# Eclipse shows javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse

I'm using some javascript files from the Spring-Security openId sample application, but eclipse is showing some red errors. The javascript files seem to be working fine despite those errors, but I'm confused about why eclipse would show the errors in my copies of the files, but not the original project I've got imported into eclipse!

The errors are in the file "jquery.query-2.1.3.js"

The first error is:

```
Syntax error on token "new", ArrayLiteralHeader expected after this token
```

On the first line of the file:

```
new function(settings) {
```

The second error is:

```
Syntax error, insert "]" to complete NewExpression
```

On the last line of the file:

```
}(jQuery.query || {}); // Pass in jQuery.query as settings object
```

Should I figure out a way to get eclipse to ignore these errors, or is there actually something I need to fix here? Sorry, I'm not very knowledgeable about javascript.

Thanks!

Comment: It's your ide (eclipse), just ignore it

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was able to ignore the files in eclipse.