# Eclipse, many Syntax errors for .js file

Tags: node.js, eclipse

I would like to ask a quick simple question which I couldn't find anywhere.

I've just started the node and the IDE I have chosen is Eclipse + Node plugin.

Btw, the IDE doesn't really help. Please see the Capture.

[Capture: Many syntax errors on Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hl1q.png)

All the error descriptions starts with `Syntax error on token ...`

This is the closest duplicate question I've found is this one.
[Eclipse shows javascript error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196054/eclipse-shows-javascript-error)

Does anyone has better way other than just ignore it? I believe there is no point to use IDE if this happens.

Comment: Are you going to tell us what version you're using? It makes a difference.

Comment: yep, using Enide.p2f Eclipse Node.js IDE 1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

It seems Eclipse  Neon  has a bug related to JavaScript:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=496348

Perhaps you are running into this?